# Is there a way to provide default values for env variables in a properties file with apache-commons?

Tags: java, apache-commons-config

I'm using `org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.5` to read config parameters from a config file. In my `application.properties`, I want to specify default values for environment variables in case one of these has not been set, e.g. like so (similar as with Spring):

```
idp.username=${env:IDP_USERNAME:defaultUsername}
```

However, while setting the env variable works fine, specifying a default value like this is not working. Unfortunately, I can't find anything related to this in the `commons-configuration2` documentation. Is this possible without explicitly checking for a missing value in the Java code? Does Spring Boot use a certain lib for this that I could also use? I don't want to bloat up my simple app with the Spring framework only to have this kind of configuration.

Simplified code example I'm currently using (here, I obviously could check each property I retrieve and replace it with a default, but I'd like to avoid this and handle it directly in the config file):

```java
private void loadConfigFile() {
        logger.info("Attempting to load `application.properties`...");
        Configurations configBuilder = new Configurations();
        try {
            Configuration props = configBuilder.properties(new File("application.properties"));

            // application config
            this.conf = new Config();
            this.conf.setAPIEndpoint(props.getString("api.endpoint"));
            this.conf.setMaxConnections(props.getInt("api.maxConnections"));
            ...

            logger.info("Config successfully loaded!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Could not load `application.properties`: {}", e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you reading application.properties with commons configuration? This can easily be done with Spring Boot?

Comment: As specified in the question, I don't use Spring Boot in this specific application and would like to avoid it. The file is just named `application.properties` for convenience.

Answer (score 3):

Commons Configuration provides a way to do [custom interpolation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html#Customizing_interpolation). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24532548/8929501) shows an example. Your [Lookup](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/interpol/Lookup.html) implementation would need to handle parsing everything past the prefix and then doing the lookup and providing the default value.